# WiFiClient arduino isn't returning what I expect from a php webpage

Tags: php, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I have a very simple php web page that simply does "echo 0". When you type in the correct address, all you see is 0 on the page. So this is fine. I am trying to activate this php page with my arduino code and get this "0" from the site, however it keeps returning this "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" instead of this "0". What am I missing? Here is the arduino code that is relevant...

```
void printWEB(WiFiClient client) {

if (client.connect(localServer, 80) == 1) {
client.print("GET /waterStatus.php?username=test&device_column=d1");  
client.println(" HTTP/1.1"); // Part of the GET request
client.println("Host: www.MYURL.com");
client.println("User-Agent: ESP8266/1.0");
client.println("Connection: close");
client.println();


 unsigned long timeoutP = millis();
 while (client.available() == 0) {
   if (millis() - timeoutP > 10000) {
      Serial.print(">>> Client Timeout: ");
      Serial.println("www.MYURL.com");
      client.stop();
      return;
   }
 }
  while(client.available()){
    String retLine = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.println(retLine);
    break; 
  }
}
delay(1000);
```

}

this last line "Serial.println(retLine);" is what I am expecting to be 0 but it is not.

Comment: The response from your web server includes one or more headers including the response code you are seeing. The response you are looking for is further down.

Comment: So how do I get to it? do another readuntil?

Comment: Yes, probably more than one. You're currently only reading until you see a carriage-return. You should read until there's no more data.

Comment: Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: You're working with an HTTP message here, not a web page. A browser will strip and interpret all the headers and present just the body for display. If you're handling the message you'll need to do that yourself. I'm not familiar with Arduino's library classes. There might be a `readAll()` method you can use. I believe there's an experimental HttpClient library that might do some of this for you.

Comment: you can use HttpClent library